# Importing library android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-library

hey guys i've been trying to import this library on android studio i just cant do it. Can someone please guide me on importing this library.

Link : https://github.com/rey5137/material

application gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app:gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.projects.jeet.materialUI"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.1.6-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

now im getting an error in my values-v23.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/mnc-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/styles_base_text.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse"/>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/mnc-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/themes_base.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat"/>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
    <style name="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- We can use the platform drawable on v23+ -->
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>

        <item name="controlBackground">@drawable/abc_control_background_material</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- We can use the platform drawable on v23+ -->
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>

        <item name="controlBackground">@drawable/abc_control_background_material</item>
    </style>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/mnc-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/styles_base.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored"/>
</resources>
```

the error is

```
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\AndroidDevKit\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: There are various interpretations for "cant do it" (such as: have no PC, need Android-Studio, have no time, do not know how to, am getting error-msgs). Some more details about what you tried (if you tried at all) and what happened might help to get an answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As described in the repo, add this dependency to your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency to build.grade in application folder:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }
}
```

Add these dependencies to build.grade in your app folder:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.1.6-SNAPSHOT'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

Comment: i get the following error Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\AndroidDevKit\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: have you synced the gradle file of application folder after adding maven

Comment: post your build.gradle please, it is not clear in comment